# How to create manual action in non-default branch github

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions

I am trying to create a manual action on a non-default branch in github. This might seem simple and I have literally copied the manual.yml given by github to my branchA on which I want to run actions, but still I am not able to manually trigger the action. Here is my attached manual.yml

```
# This is a basic workflow that is manually triggered

name: Manual workflow

# Controls when the action will run. Workflow runs when manually triggered using the UI
# or API.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    # Inputs the workflow accepts.
    inputs:
      name:
        # Friendly description to be shown in the UI instead of 'name'
        description: 'WorkFlow'
        # Default value if no value is explicitly provided
        default: 'Workflow'
        # Input has to be provided for the workflow to run
        required: true

env:
  AWS_REGION: us-east-1                   # set this to your preferred AWS region, e.g. us-west-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY: repo           # set this to your Amazon ECR repository name
  ECS_SERVICE: service_name                 # set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER: cluster_name                 # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: aws/task_def.json # set this to the path to your Amazon ECS task definition
                                               # file, e.g. .aws/task-definition.json
  CONTAINER_NAME: container           # set this to the name of the container in the
                                               # containerDefinitions section of your task definition

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        # Build a docker container and
        # push it to ECR so that it can
        # be deployed to ECS.
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
        container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Any idea what I have done wrong? I am not able to trigger workflow on branchA!

Comment: For this kind of specific test, you would need to have the workflow file on the `default` branch for it to appear on the repository `Actions` tab. Then, you would be able to select the branch from the Actions tab for this workflow execution, to choose the specific version of this workflow file you want to test (according to the branch).

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember to commit this workflow in the branchA too?

If you don't have the same yml file in another branch, you can't.

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in the question, I have created the yml in the concerned branch where I want to trigger workflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay, verify if your yml file has create in the directory `.github/workflows/`. I get your code and try to test, everything works for me. You can see my test here: https://imgur.com/a/XUjQWmh